# Duplicate "function(){}.call(this)" in Uglified JS

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs, uglifier

My uglified (using rails uglifier) javascript ends like this:

```
/* ... actual code */}.call(this),function(){}.call(this),function(){}.call(this),function(){}.call(this),function(){}.call(this),function(){}.call(this);
```

Or for humans:

```
}.call(this),
function(){}.call(this),
function(){}.call(this),
function(){}.call(this),
function(){}.call(this),
function(){}.call(this);
```

Uglifier should be reducing the number of bytes in the final product. I've got some empty coffee files (but more than 6) so as far as I know, it's not because rails is processing them. Anyone know why this would be happening?

Comment: That code alone does nothing. Well, it may throw an exception on line 1 - which I suppose is *something*...

Comment: no, sorry I just excluded the stuff before that. I know that from line 2 it's not doing anything but it's a bit peculiar.

Comment: Do you have some empty files in your js folders? Maybe some .gitkeep files?

Comment: Is that the only output?  What do your input and configuration files look like?

Comment: @AustinMullins: Empty files, I hadn't thought of that - I'll check (you'd think uglifier would be smarter though).

Comment: @Tracker1 nope, that's just how the file ends - the uglified javascript is working fine though (as expected) - it's just silly that it ends like this (especially considering the whole point is to save bytes)

Comment: @AustinMullins There are empty files but there are at least 6 so it's unlikely they're the cause

Comment: Also, why the downvote people?

Comment: What file types is your Rails apps configured to uglify?

Comment: I haven't explicitly changed anything so it's the defaults. As far as I know it just processes all javascript (including parsed coffee script)

Comment: Possibly `function(){}.call(this)` code from other empty files just goes elsewhere in the output, and only from these 5 is cumulated in the end.

Comment: i get this sometimes. i just RegExp it out and move on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> CoffeeScript wraps all files to a function that is invoked
>   immediately. This prevents variable declarations from multiple files
>   from interfering with each other when the files are concatenated
>   (which is what Rails asset pipeline is doing). Sure, those empty
>   functions could be removed in minification process, but UglifyJS isn't
>   currently able to perform such optimisation.

https://github.com/lautis/uglifier/issues/82